# All pages showing "page expired" after migration

Tags: session, laravel-5.8

One of my clients wants to migrate an old Laravel application. Their ICT department dumped the code on our server but could not get it to work. After some configuration we get the login page, but upon login, it is showing "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again."

Laravel 5.8
Dockerized
Nginx proxy

Problem 1: html returned does not point to public folder. I tried to fix it a number of ways but all to no avail. Only thing that seems to serve all the files in public folder is this .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/public/assets/$1 [L,R=301]
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^/assets/(.*)$ /public/assets/$1 [L,QSA]


    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

</IfModule>
```

Problem 2: csrf tokens could be the culprit

I disabled the VerifyCsrfToken middleware in Kernel.php

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [

        'web' => [

            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,

            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,

            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,

            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,

            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,

            // \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,

            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

        ],



        'api' => [

            'throttle:60,1',

            'bindings',

        ],

    ];
```

Problem 3: regenerate key and update .env

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Problem 4: file permissions on storage folder

I gave all permissions recursive to this folder

```
chmod 777 -R ./storage
```

For debugging I set this value in .env file

```
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

Session driver is set to value 'file', but tested with value 'array' but made no difference.

```
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
```

I am new to Laravel and I am looking for a way to fix this or how to debug issue properly.

Comment: in `config/session.php` check if `secure` is `false`

Comment: Secure is set to false: 'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),